# What is the PMEG?

Tags: learning, resources

Many answers in the forum refer to **PMEG**? What is it? A book, a tool, or perhaps a person with Esperanto super powers?

Comment: Have you [looked it up](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html)? Check this in Wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plena_Manlibro_de_Esperanta_Gramatiko

Comment: The purpose of a Stack Exchange community is to be the place where one would look up and find answers. But this discussion is better on the Meta site.

Comment: I asked that because when anybody asks a question, that person is supposed to *"Provide details and share research with your question."*. A simple search would have answered your question in its current form. But I feel you're going more for the *"why is it mentioned so much?"*. Well, it is very good, and it's been on the internet, accessible to everybody for quite some time. That helps a lot.

Answer (score 5):

PMEG is a book with the title [*Plena manlibro de Esperanta gramatiko*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html). The current main editor is [Bertil Wennergren](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertilo_Wennergren), a known Esperantist and music performer. PMEG or PoMeGo, the big apple, is available online and is considered by many the most comprehensive grammar book.